# I am not able to connect to my ORACLE RDS through SQL developer

Tags: amazon-web-services, rds

I created a ORACLE RDS under the free tier and I am getting the following message when connecting:

The network adapter could not establish the connection.

I configured the inbound rule under the security groups by allowing all traffic for my IP but the problem persists.
I am using the hostname as provided as the endpoint in the AWS UI. The port is 1521. The username and password is what I configured initially before creating the db instance and the SID is oracle. Has anyone faced this issue before even after adding the inbound rule?

Note: I am also running an EC2 instance at the same time.

Comment: Looking at your security groups will help. Please ensure 1521 is open. If this does not help you. It could be an issue with different VPCs

Comment: I had to make the RDS publicly accessible but still had to provide the my IP in the security groups.